# How do I get form data from jQuery to ASP.NET controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm completely new to web development. After reading documentations and googling, I'm left just as confused about this question. I have a controller, a model, and a view that does a form.submit() (front end code is not from me). How do I get the form data on the controller? The code below does nothing at all (no errors, no values).

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManagerAnalysis(FormCollection collection)
    {
        AnalysisModel model = new AnalysisModel();

        model.analysisName = collection["analysisName"];
        model.description = collection["description"];
        model.dueDate = collection["dueDate"];
        model.inviteInfo = collection["inviteInfo"];
        model.manual = collection["manual"];
        model.custom = collection["custom"];

        return View();
    }
```

**view**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Wizard";
}


<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h2>Analysis Setup</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox">

                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h2>New</h2>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a class="collapse-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Config option 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Config option 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="close-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <h2>
                       General Information
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                           Get started by providing general details and inviting others to work with you
                    </p>

                    <form id="form" action="#" class="wizard-big">
                        <h1>Initial</h1>
                        <fieldset>
                            <h2>Basics</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Analysis Name *</label>
                                        <input id="analysisName" name="analysis" type="text" class="form-control required" >

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Description *</label>
                                     <div>  @Html.TextArea("name", new { @class = "form-control required" })</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Due date *</label>
                                        <input id="date" name="date" type="date" class="form-control required">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="font-size: 180px;color: #e5e5e5 "></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </fieldset>
                        <h1>Collboration</h1>
                        <fieldset>
                            <h2>Invite Others</h2>
                            <p>Invite others to work with you by providing their email. We will get them set up in no time.</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Manual* </label>
                                        <p>Enter the number of employees whose information you will be entering manually (no invitation)</p>
                                        <input id="manualNumber" name="number" type="number" class="form-control required" >
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Invitation* </label>

                                        <p>Enter the number of employees you will be inviting to enter their own data</p>
                                        <input id="inviteNumber" name="number" type="number" class="form-control required">
                                    </div>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>



                        <h1>Invite</h1>
                        <fieldset>
                            <h2>Invite Your Employees</h2>
                            <p>Now enter the name and email of the employees you chose to invite in the pervious step</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name * </label>
                                        <input  name="employeeName" type="text" class="form-control required">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email * </label>

                                        <input  name="email" type="email" class="form-control required email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div><button type="button" onClick="nextInvite" class="btn btn-success">Next Invite</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>


                        <h1>Finish</h1>
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                                    <div>
                                     <h3>Would you like to create custom forms for your employees?</h3>
                                        <label>
                                           Yes<input id="yes" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                        </label>
                                    <label>
                                        No
                                        <input id="no" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
                                    </label>

                                </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/iCheck/iCheckStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/wizardStepsStyles")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/wizardSteps")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/iCheck")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/validate")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            function nextInvite() {
                var input1 = document.getElementById("employeeName");
                var input2 = document.getElementById("email");

                input1.value = " ";
                input2.value = " ";
                alert("shitttt!");
            };

            $("#wizard").steps();
            $("#form").steps({
                bodyTag: "fieldset",
                onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                    // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
                    if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Forbid suppressing "Warning" step if the user is to young
                    if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age").val()) < 18) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var form = $(this);

                    // Clean up if user went backward before
                    if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
                        // To remove error styles
                        $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
                        $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
                    }

                    // Disable validation on fields that are disabled or hidden.
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";

                    // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
                    return form.valid();
                },

                onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    var form = $(this);

                    // Disable validation on fields that are disabled.
                    // At this point it's recommended to do an overall check (mean ignoring only disabled fields)
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";

                    // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    var form = $(this);

                    // Submit form input
                    form.submit();
                }
            }).validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    element.before(error);
                },
                rules: {
                    confirm: {
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

The view is longer but the rest is validation stuff, which I don't think is relevant here

**And the Model**

```
    namespace coach.Models
{
    public class AnalysisModel
    {


        public string analysisName { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string dueDate { get; set; }
        public string manual { get; set; }
        public string inviteInfo { get; set; }
        public string custom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am not new to programming so if you can point me to some resources I might be able to find something. Thanks!

**Edit**

Another method in the controller that's actually getting hit:

```
  //GET MangerView
   public ActionResult ManagerAnalysis() {
        Console.WriteLine("getting first controller");
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: You should never need `FormCollection` in MVC - change your method to `public ActionResult ManagerAnalysis(AnalysisModel model)` and it will be correctly bound. What is `onFinished`? and where is it called? And are you sure `var form = $(this);` is actually your form. And are you even hitting your controller method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Correct me if am wrong, he can use `model` instead of `FormCollection` only if he binds it in the `view` right? But looking at his view, he hasn't binded the `model`...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, It will bind because the `name` attributes of the controls match the property names. But there is nothing MVC about any of this code, in particular the view :)

Comment: Oh right.. Got some extra knowledge, afterall MVC decides `model` values based on the names right.. :) Thank you for clarifying.. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put brekpoints in and tested. I am not actually hitting the controller. I do have another controller method (Look at edit). Do methods overload?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao look at my edit. I tried sticking in print statements before which didn't help, but using breaks helped. Don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: That's your GET method. But I have no idea what your script is doing or how its being called. If you replace your `<form>` tags with `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { .... }` so it generates the correct `action` attribute and add a submit button in your form you will see how it works.

Comment: The form is a jQuery wizard from my understanding. So the finish button seems to come by default. I'm going to post the whole view

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thanks a lot. That was it. I can mark it as an answer if you put it down there, if you would like that. Again thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form` is missing `action url` to post the `data`. So action should be having value `@Url.Action("ManagerAnalysis","ControllerName")` instead of `"#"`

Something like below:

```
<form id="form" action="@Url.Action("ManagerAnalysis","ControllerName")" class="wizard-big">
```